# For each quarter between two dates, add rows quarter by quarter in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, with types int, datetime, datetime:

```
id    start date    end date
--    ----------    ----------
1     2019-04-02    2020-09-17
2     2019-08-10    2020-08-10
```

Here is create/insert:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.something
(
  id           int, 
  [start date] datetime, 
  [end date]   datetime
);

INSERT dbo.something(id,[start date],[end date]) 
  VALUES(1,'20190402','20200917'),(2,'20190810','20200810');
```

What is a SQL query that can produce these results:

```
id    Year    Quarter
--    ----    ----------
1     2019    2
1     2019    3
1     2019    4
1     2020    1
1     2020    2
1     2020    3
2     2019    3
2     2019    4
2     2020    1
2     2020    2
2     2020    3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot make another reference table/etc, you can use DATEDIFF (and DATEPART) using quarters, and then some simple date arithmetic.

The logic below is simply to find, for each startdate, the first quarter and then the number of additional quarters to get to the maximum. Then do a SELECT where the additional quarters are added to the startdate, to get each quarter.

The hardest part of the query to understand imo is the `WITH numberlist` section - all this does is generate a series of integers between 0 and the maximum number of quarters difference. If you already have a numbers table, you can use that instead.

Key code part is below, and here's a full [DB_Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=600ebf60d34c444876818f1efdef7914) with some additional test data.

```
CREATE TABLE #yourtable (id int, startdate date, enddate date)
INSERT INTO #yourtable (id, startdate, enddate) VALUES
(1, '2019-04-02', '2020-09-17'),
(2, '2019-08-10', '2020-08-20')

; WITH number_list AS
        -- list of ints from 0 to maximum number of quarters
        (SELECT n 
            FROM (SELECT ones.n + 10*tens.n AS n
                    FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
                         (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n)
                ) AS a
            WHERE n <= (SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(quarter,startdate,enddate)) FROM #yourtable)
        )
    SELECT  id,
            YEAR(DATEADD(quarter, number_list.n, startdate)) AS [Year],
            DATEPART(quarter, DATEADD(quarter, number_list.n, startdate)) AS [Quarter]
    FROM    (SELECT id, startdate, DATEDIFF(quarter,startdate,enddate) AS num_additional_quarters FROM #yourtable) yt
            CROSS JOIN number_list
    WHERE   number_list.n <= yt.num_additional_quarters 


DROP TABLE #yourtable
```

Comment: `'2019-04-02'` is a bad literal format, [check what it returns under, say, `SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0d45a99768c255f9d91c5f35d0222621). Much safer to use `'20190402'` then there is no possibility for SQL Server to misinterpret.

Comment: Gah that is awful @AaronBertrand - thanks for pointing that out! I thought that using the dashes was the preferred format but I've learned something new. Thanks!

Comment: It sure is. I've mentioned it in more articles and presentations than I can remember.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a recursive CTE.  This version switches to counting quarters from year 0:

```
with cte as (
      select id, 
             year(start_date) * 4 +  datepart(quarter, start_date) - 1 as yyyyq,
             year(end_date) * 4 + datepart(quarter, end_date) - 1 as end_yyyyq
      from t
      union all
      select id, yyyyq + 1, end_yyyyq
      from cte
      where yyyyq < end_yyyyq
     )
select id, yyyyq / 4 as year, (yyyyq % 4) + 1 as quarter
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=59223eb40c17bf5d9595f11bd9009839) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: It's exactly why I am looking for ! Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

First create a date dimension table which contains date, corresponding quarter and year. Then use below query to get the result. Tweak column and table name according to your schema.

```
with q_date as
(
select 1 as id, '2019-04-02' :: date as start_date, '2020-09-17' :: date as end_date
UNION ALL
select 2 as id, '2019-08-10' :: date as start_date, '2020-08-10' :: date as end_date
)


select qd.id, dd.calendar_year, dd.calendar_quarter_number 
from dim_date dd, q_date qd 
where dd.date_dmk between qd.start_date and qd.end_date
group by qd.id, dd.calendar_year, dd.calendar_quarter_number
order by qd.id, dd.calendar_year, dd.calendar_quarter_number;
```

Comment: Group By 1,2,3   ??

Comment: it's a lazy shortcut to replace column aliases. You can always use column names in group by.

Comment: Well aware, but have you tried the GROUP BY in SQL Server ?

Comment: It would be a terrible idea even if it were legal in SQL Server, IMHO. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal

Comment: I thought you might also fix `'2019-04-02' :: date` which is not legal in SQL Server.