# SQL Server UTC string comparison not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, timezone

we have two SQL Servers.

We have the following example SQL to recreate an issue we are facing.

```
select * from (

select '2020-11-04 08:00:00' as start
union all
select '2020-11-04 08:00:00' as start

) a

where cast(convert(date, a.start) as datetime) + cast(Cast(a.start AS time) as datetime) > '2020-11-04 08:00:00'
```

when we run this query of the servers, one server returns two records and the other returns zero records.

Both should should return zero records.

We think there is some setting that needs to be adjusted on the server to correct this. Could you help us out? Thanks

Comment: Why vote to close?? Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Because you have too much rep / experience to posting this without making any real attempt at debugging. The first thing you should do is remove the where clause and add all of the expressions used in it to the select list to actually SEE what your logic computes. But why bother with all the casts and math? The values you posted can be directly and safely converted to datetime in one cast. And since your question has zero relationship to UTC as posted, this suggests your actual issue might be very different.

Comment: Strings have no timezone, dates do. *Don't* handle dates as strings to begin with. If you care about timezones use `datetimeoffset`. Dates have no format either, they are binary values.

Comment: BTW what's the point of separately parsing the components of the date? Were you trying to bypass the localized parsing used by `datetime`? You could have used `datetime2` instead eg `cast(a.date as datetime2(0))` or `datetimeoffset`, eg `cast(a.date as datetimeoffset(0))`. This will generate a datetimeoffset in the server's timezone.

Comment: I did attempt, after I couldn't figure it out I posted this question. The issue was I assumed 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss' was UTC and SQL would interpret it as UTC, as it has been doing when the language was set to us-english, but turns out my understanding was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the servers have different base languages/settings for dates - though obviously this is just a guess.

One may consider `2020-11-04 08:00:00` as 8:00am on November 4, whereas the other treats it as 11 April.

These can be based on

- Windows regional settings
- Default language of SQL Server

You should use a universal datetime format e.g., `20201104 08:00:00`. If you change the query above to use these, and the servers return the same answer as each other, I think you've found the issue.

Of course, the servers could be in different timezones and/or haven't accounted for daylight savings - but `SELECT getdate()` should tell you what the server dates are.

Comment: A far better solution would be to use proper date values instead of strings. Dates have no format and aren't affected by the server's locale, they are binary values. If timezones are important, the correct type is `datetimeoffset`.

Comment: Completely agree @Panagiotis - hence the statement that they should use a universal format.

Comment: I said the opposite - that no strings should be used at all. `datetime` has no format, it's a binary value

Comment: Sorry I don't understand @Panagiotis - where is the string used? Do you mean the quotes around dates? If so, how does one get `CREATE TABLE #d (d date); INSERT INTO #d (d) SELECT '20201104';` to work without the date quoted?

Comment: Looks like  one of our servers had the language set to "us-english" and the "British". The British one need to be changed to "us-english". I was under the impression that "2020-11-01 00:00:00" was universal format ie iso 1860, so I assumed sql would interpreted this as UTC.

Comment: I used set LANGUAGE = 'us-english' to resolve this.

Comment: Re `2020-11-04` format - I thought so too Mokky! However, @AaronBertrand taught me something new - see comments in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63958638/14267425