# How to filter IDs based on dates?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have the following table:

```
ID | DATES
---+-----------
1   02-09-2010
2   03-08-2011
1   08-01-2011
3   04-03-2010
```

I am looking for IDs who had at least one date before 05-01-2010 AND at least one date after 05-02-2010

I tried the following:

```
WHERE tb1.DATES < '05-01-2010' AND tb1.DATES > '05-02-2010'
```

I don't think it's correct because I wasn't getting the right IDs when I did that and there's something wrong with that logic.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Create two subqueries, one of them select IDs where their date is before, and the other is for after, then [intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql)

Comment: The above logic should work but i think logically it's wrong. date< 5 Jan 2010 and date > 5 Feb 2010. There wouldn't be any dates that match that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL command `SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE tb1.DATES < '05-01-2010' AND tb1.DATES > '05-02-2010'` is asking "find all the rows where the 'dates' field is before 1 May and after 2 May" which - when put in English - is obviously none of them.

Instead, the command should be asking "find all the IDs which have a record that is before 1 May, and another record after 2 May" - creating the need to look at multiple records for each ID.

As @Martheen suggested, you could do this with two (sub)queries e.g.,

```
SELECT A.ID
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT tb1.ID
      FROM mytable tb1
      WHERE tb1.[dates] < '20100501'
    ) AS A
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT tb1.ID
      FROM mytable tb1
      WHERE tb1.[dates] > '20100502'
    ) AS B
    ON A.ID = B.ID;
```

or using INTERSECT

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb1.ID
    FROM mytable tb1
    WHERE tb1.[dates] < '20100501'
INTERSECT
    SELECT mt2.ID
    FROM mytable mt2
    WHERE mt2.[dates] > '20100502';
```

The use of DISTINCT in the above is so that you only get one row per ID, no matter how many rows they have before/after the relevant dates.

You could also do it via GROUP BY and HAVING - which in this particular case is easy as if any dates are before 1 May, then their earliest date must be before 1 May (and correspondingly for their max data and 2 May) e.g.,

```
SELECT mt1.ID
    FROM mytable mt1
    GROUP BY mt1.ID
    HAVING MIN(mt1.[dates]) < '20100501' AND MAX(mt1.[dates]) > '20100502';
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8f073c8e99e2ecf1fbda58f12ac9085) with all 3 of these; all provide the same answer (one row, with ID = 1).

Finally, you should use an *unambiguous* format for your dates. My preferred one of these is 'yyyyMMdd' with no dashes/slashes/etc (as these make them ambiguous).

Different countries/servers/etc will convert the dates you have there differently e.g., [SQL Server UTC string comparison not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64679099/sql-server-utc-string-comparison-not-working)

Answer (score -1):

This is one solution to use between to specify range.

```
SELECT * from Table_name where
From_date BETWEEN '2013-01-03'AND '2013-01-09'
```

Other solution is to what you mentioned but see that the logic is correct

```
SELECT * from Table_name where
From_date > '2010-01-05'AND From_date <'2010-02-05'
```

Comment: Is this doing what the OP wants e.g., "looking for IDs who had at least one date before 05-01-2010 AND at least one date after 05-02-2010"?

Comment: Actually in the above example I have just selected all columns. If ID is to be selected just do SELECT ID from ... Doing select * will help analyse which records are selected and if selected records are correct.