# How to turn null date values to varchar and use where statement in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, northwind

I was told to get all orders that were made after the 5th may of 1996 and include not shipped ones.
NULL values should be 'Not Shipped'. It works, but I can't compare dates anymore.
I'm sure there is a way to do that properly that i don't know. Any ideas?

```
SELECT [OrderID] AS 'Order Number', 
CASE 
    WHEN [ShippedDate] IS NULL THEN 'Not Shipped' 
END AS 'Shipped Date' 
FROM Orders
WHERE [ShippedDate] IS NULL OR [ShippedDate] > '05/06/1996' -- This line doesn't work
```

Comment: Try the default date format `'1996-05-06'`

Comment: @Juergen - That is probably the answer to the question. However, as pointed out to me by Aaron Bertrand, that is also an ambiguous date format (I made the same assumption that it was OK). See comments on https://stackoverflow.com/a/63958638/14267425 for info, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64679099/sql-server-utc-string-comparison-not-working for a recent example, and I suggest you use '19960506' instead

Comment: Also, need to get the correct relational operator (> or >=) based on date chosen e.g.,  'made after the 5th may of 1996' would be `>= '19960506` or `> '19960505` but not `> '19960506'` as the latter would skip those on 5th May.

Comment: I forgot to mention that problem is that not null values become null. I tried to do ELSE [ShippedDate] but it throws an exception

Comment: From [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments): "ELSE _else_result_expression_
Is the expression returned if no comparison operation evaluates to TRUE. If this argument is omitted and no comparison operation evaluates to TRUE, CASE returns NULL."

Comment: So what's the issue?   `ELSE [ShippedDate]` will not work as you are mixing data types in the same column.  That's why you're getting the exception.   I would have a column of just [Shipped Date] and have another like [Shipped Status] column where you do that case statement and `else 'Shipped'`.  If they have to be in the same column you'd need to convert [Shipped Date] in the ELSE to VARCHAR.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @TimMylott The rules of [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) apply to the `case` _expression_ (not _statement_) and would cause `'Not Shipped'` to be converted, unsuccessfully, to match the data type of `ShippedDate`. (We assume that the column is some sort of date/time data type, but the OP hasn't seen fit to disclose the DDL for the table.) The `where` clause references the table column so "I can't compare dates anymore" remains a mystery.

Comment: @HABO you're right, good call, I'll fix my answer so it's more accurate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `ELSE [ShippedDate]` to the case expression will not work as @HABO pointed out due to the rules of [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) would cause the `'Not Shipped'` to be converted unsuccessfully to match the data type of `ShippedDate`.  Assuming ShippedDate is a datetime data type.

Running the following example throws that exception:

```
DECLARE @testdata TABLE
    (
        [OrderID] INT
      , [ShippedDate] DATETIME
    );

INSERT INTO @testdata (
                          [OrderID]
                        , [ShippedDate]
                      )
VALUES ( 1, GETDATE())
     , ( 2, NULL );

SELECT [OrderID]
     , CASE WHEN [ShippedDate] IS NULL THEN 'Not Shipped'
            ELSE [ShippedDate]
       END AS 'Shipped Date'
FROM   @testdata
WHERE  [ShippedDate] IS NULL
       OR [ShippedDate] > '1996-05-06'; --use a standard data format here
```

You the get:
[image]

What is happening is SQL Server, base on those rules, is converting `'Not Shipped'` to the data type of your `'Shipped Date'` column, which the value is not a valid datetime and throws the error.

Couple options, add it as just another column where you return the ShippedDate but then have something like a Status Column:

```
SELECT [OrderID]
     , [ShippedDate] --Give the shipped date as it's own separate column
     , CASE WHEN [ShippedDate] IS NULL THEN 'Not Shipped'
            ELSE 'Shipped' --Then have a Shipped status
       END AS 'Shipped Status'
FROM   @testdata
WHERE  [ShippedDate] IS NULL
       OR [ShippedDate] > '1996-05-06'; --use a standard data format here
```

Giving you results of:

```
OrderID     ShippedDate             Shipped Status
----------- ----------------------- --------------
1           2020-11-05 09:35:32.653 Shipped
2           NULL                    Not Shipped
```

If they have to be in the same column, then you can convert ShippedDate in the ELSE part of your statement, use [FROMAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which will convert it for you and then you can then define the format in which the DATETIME value is returned in:

```
SELECT [OrderID]
     , CASE WHEN [ShippedDate] IS NULL THEN 'Not Shipped'
            ELSE FORMAT([ShippedDate], 'yyyy-MM-dd')
       END AS 'Shipped Date'
FROM   @testdata
WHERE  [ShippedDate] IS NULL
       OR [ShippedDate] > '1996-05-06'; --use a standard data format here
```

Giving you the results of:

```
OrderID     Shipped Date
----------- --------------
1           2020-11-05
2           Not Shipped
```

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
 SELECT [OrderID] AS 'Order Number', 
    CASE 
        WHEN [ShippedDate] IS NULL THEN 'Not Shipped' 
        else [ShippedDate]
    END AS 'Shipped Date' 
    FROM Orders
    WHERE [ShippedDate] IS NULL OR [ShippedDate] > '05/06/1996'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a standard date format:

```
WHERE ShippedDate IS NULL OR
      ShippedDate > '1996-05-06'
```